# Algorthm for discerning which top X values in a list are statistically ranked higher than the bottom Y

Tags: uncertainty, ranks, pruning

Given a ranked list, which contains values with high uncertainty, I would like to remove as many of the middle values that have high overlap in uncertainties as possible, and be left with more or less two lists... the top X values and worst Y values. I will use the top X values for screening and other things.

```
item name    |    value     |    uncertainty
item1              -10              2.3
item2              -8.1             1.4
item3              -3.8             5.3
item4              -3.7             2.1
item5              -2.3             1.7
item6              -1.8             2.2
item7              -0.6             3.7
item8              -0.4             2.6
item9               0.3             1.9
item10              3.4             2.8
item11              5.3             3.2
item12              11.4            1.6
```

in practice the lists are much longer, the values much closer together. Clearly, the top and bottom value do not overlap in this case, and by visual inspection one could get a few more values out. Also fairly clearly, alot of the middle values overlap alot, but do not overlap with the best or worst value.

There are a few primitive approaches that could be employed, like take the best value and worst value, do they overlap? if no, add to X and Y list respectively, then take second best and second worst etc. but, I can't help think there must be a more formal way to do this.

Perhaps cross validation is not the right forum either, I will happily remove this and post elsewhere if there is a better place.

Comment: Unfortunately, "screening and other things" isn't adequate guidance for solving this problem.  Could you say more about how this result will be used and/or interpreted?

Comment: @whuber I only want to do experiments on the best results. Unfortunately, with such high uncertainty in my model, it is hard to believe the ranking, with the exception of the obvious best and worst being better/worse than each other.  I am prepared to make sacrifices. I must take the best item, but aside from that, at what point do I stop? If the second best item overlapped with the worst item, I would stop at the top item. My model would clearly not be useful at ranking. How far down the list can I go before items cease to be statistically better than random selection?

Comment: My very last sentence above may have unwittingly summed up what I am trying to accomplish. I don't know if my original question reflects this.

Comment: You might be looking for something like [Tukey's HSD test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Tukey+HSD+score%3A1).  Would this be close?